# PHP - How do i delete data from database automatically after 24 hour of insertion

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I want to delete data from database after every 24hours insertion.

For example: A user is added today and he is not active, after 24hours the user will be automatically deleted.

I intend doing this without cron because cron is not in my local/offline server.

Please i really need your help.

Comment: the only way you can do this with php is in the database row have a last logged on time stamp. if the user comes back after 24 hours delete the record. PHP is only run when the webpage is loaded and will not run behind the scenes

Comment: MySQL has scheduled events (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html), you might be able to use these - log a date in the database and every day schedule something like `DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE date=...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use

```
DELETE FROM your_table 
WHERE your_date_col < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

and use the mysql scheduled events

could be somethings like this

```
CREATE EVENT my_dayly_event
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    COMMENT 'delete old values.'
    DO
    DELETE FROM your_table 
    WHERE your_date_col < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

anyway take a look a this doc.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html  ... could be useful

Comment: i don't know how to use the scheduler event please can you write it for me?

Comment: ok bro that means with this i will have to wait for 1 day before i see the result. right?

Comment: This is a sample  ... you can study the doc and try what is better for you  .. you can change the frequence ( 1 HOUR or 1 MINUTE) for debugging or test ..